# Set Web Part Page Columns for Equal Width

Tags: column

I have a web part page with header, footer and 3 columns.  I want the three columns to be of equal width.  I have searched but can't find and simple CSS code to apply.  I don't have access to SPD.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css:

```
table.ms-core-tableNoSpace > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td {
    width: 33.3%;
}
```